# How can I append text to html source in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, fckeditor

I use CKEditor in my web-application. By click on one link i appends some text to CKEditor. It works fine. But when I open `source` tab, i can not append this text to the existing source. Can you help me how can I do it? Thank you in advance. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are trying to append HTML text, you could use the createFromHtml method like this for example:

```
var imgHtml = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml("<img src=" + imageSrcUrl + " alt='' align='right'/>");
```

where imageSrcUrl is the image location and then you can insert it into the ckeditor source like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.body.insertElement(imgHtml);
```

There are other methods like insertHtml or insertText, you can check the [CKEditor APIs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html) for more details on these.

Comment: var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<img src="hello.png" border="0" title="Hello" />' );
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertElement( element );  Ref: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertElement

Comment: Saved my day :) insertHtml is automaticly closing tags insertElement is not :)

Comment: For me Instead of `CKEDITOR.instances.body` ID of my textarea worked `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1`

Answer (score 9):

According to this post
http://www.techsirius.com/2013/09/dynamically-insert-string-into-ckeditor.html

You can insert text into ckeditor(textarea). You just need to give an unique ID to ckeditor(textarea) after that follow below code.

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
  function insertIntoCkeditor(str){
    CKEDITOR.instances[ckeditor_id].insertText(str);
  }
</script>
```

This is working demo link.
http://demo.techsirius.com/demo/dynamically-insert-string-into-ckeditor

Answer (score 4):

To append HTML *at the end* you can do this:

```
var targetEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.idOfYourTextarea;
var range = targetEditor.createRange();
range.moveToElementEditEnd(range.root);
targetEditor.insertHtml("<p>foo</p>", 'html', range);
```

Answer (score 1):

Other sample working function :

```
  function insertIntoCkeditor(str,url){

  var tagHtml = ''+str+'';

    //CKEDITOR.instances['bilgi'].insertText(tagHtml);
    CKEDITOR.instances['bilgi'].insertHtml(tagHtml);
    //CKEDITOR.instances.body.insertElement(tagHtml);
  }

onclick="insertIntoCkeditor('Parakazan','Http://www.parakazan.org')">
```